# Fan start disrupts ATmega328P's functioning

Tags: atmega328p

I have a 12 V power supply unit. To its terminals a 12 V fan is connected and in parallel a L7805 voltage regulator (regulates to 5 V). I use this 5 V line to power an ATmega328P controlling a few utilities (LCD, thermistor, encoder, 12 V heater element).

[image]

When I power on the fan this apparently disturbs the ATmega328P's operation, crashing the LCD readings. I assume this is due to a voltage sag from fan overcurrent absorption. This sag probably disturbs the L7805 operation and therefore the LCD.

What is an effective and simple way to resolve this issue? Power line splitting into analog and digital? Use of capacitors? But how?

UPDATE:
The disturbance was arising also when I disconnected the fan. So I have added a 10 μF capacitor at the L7805's input and a diode in parallel to the fan. The capacitor is supposed to avoid disturbances to pass the L7805, but honestly I think this is superfluous. In contrast, the diode is supposed to prevent voltage spikes when I shut off the fan. The circuit now appears stable on fan run/start. Unfortunately  when I heat the heating element, at around 170°C something happens and the LCD starts having new problems. But I think this is a matter for another post.

[image]

Comment: Your block diagram is missing details. Please add schematics and PCB layout to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Your schematic shows no control of the fan, so how is it turning on and off?

Comment: Put a 100uF electrolytic capacitor on the input to the 7805 regulator. Have a read of the datasheet for your 7805 and make sure you comply with the manufacturer’s recommendations.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am working on a soldered protoboard, I control the fan with a bipolar switch (with integrated led), however I noticed a strange behavior(too low output voltage) so I simply decided to remove the switch and simply activate the fan with direct contact done by hand for debug purposes. When I make contact, it crashed the LCD readings. I made this simplified scheme only for display reasons on this post. Thanks

Comment: @Kartman According to this datasheet https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/22676/STMICROELECTRONICS/7805CV.html at "Figure 17,Fixed output regulator" scheme, the input capacitor should be 0,33 uF. I used three 0,1 uF since I didn't have a 0,33 uF one. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Kartman do you suggest increasing capacitance anway? thx

Comment: @Justme I have added an updated scheme to the post. I added a few corrections and now the fan seems to be working a charm. There's a new LCD disturbance however when the heater temperature gets close to 170°C. I don't have a PCB, but only a tad confused protoboard. I never made a PCB.

Comment: Well there's many things wrong. Arduino drives base of transistor without resistor. Enough current can flow to damage things. The LCD also can't work because there's GND on supply pin. Pushing the rotary button will short power supply. Are these schematics accurate and match the circuit you made?

Comment: @Justme It was not accurate, sorry. I edited the scheme. I don't know if the rotary encoder in the scheme is correctly connected as the pins have different naming, however I know it is connected correctly in reality. I cleaned the protoboard and rechecked all connections. I also added the resistor you suggested(1k). The only problem I have now is that when the heater heats up to a certain level, the Atmega seems to be restarting all of a sudden. I'm trying to understand why. Thank you for checking the scheme.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems that could happen. The first is common mode voltages. If high current exits through a ground wire/trace on the same PCB it will create a voltage. The voltage is from the current flowing through the resistance of the wire back to the ground of the power supply.

If you have an oscilloscope or DMM with a max function, you could see this voltage by measuring with a meter the max voltage of the cable or trace and make sure it's low when the fan or other loads are switching on and off.

The other thing that needs to be measured is the voltage on the 12V line with respect to power supply ground (at the supply) and also the 5V line with respect to PCB ground. If you are seeing any spikes when the loads are turning on and off (should be at least 5% or less of the voltage rail) then that could prevent the ATmega from functioning correctly.

If you are seeing spikes/flucuations, then you'll need to use capacitors and inductors to control the spikes and/or change the grounding system. It would also be a good idea to run the ground of the high power loads seperate from the ATmega ground.